# Vite plugin load() of index.html?

Tags: plugins, vite

I can implement transformIndexHtml but this only works if there is an index.html.   I want index.html to be entirely generated by my plugin but I don't see a corresponding loadIndexHtml() hook.

I have a "harness.tsx" which is the top level of my app that I dynamically generate in this way inside load().  Putting a real index.html in the root doesn't really work for us unfortunately so we need to generate it on the fly.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this?